# Where to specify ssl_cert_file and alike at Azure?

Tags: postgresql, azure

For parameters in `postgresql.conf` typically located in the `data` folder, where are they at Azure? For example,

```
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = ...
ssl_key_file = ...
ssl_ciphers =
```

There are only 2 `ssl` parameters in `Server parameters`
[image]

Comment: how are you setting up your postgres?

Comment: @DanielA.White what section/tab during the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to configure SSL certificate, you need to **use connection strings that are pre-defined in the "Connection Strings" settings under your server in the Azure portal include the required parameters for common languages to connect to your database server using TLS. The TLS parameter varies based on the connector, for example `ssl=true` or `sslmode=require` or `sslmode=required` and other variations.**

The following command is an example of the psql connection string:

`psql "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt host=mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com dbname=postgres user=myusern@mydemoserver"`

Refer below documents for better understanding:

[Configure TLS connectivity in Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security)

[How do I know if I'm using SSL/TLS with root certificate verification?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-certificate-rotation#3-how-do-i-know-if-im-using-ssltls-with-root-certificate-verification)