# No Data encryption option for Azure Database for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, azure

Based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-data-encryption-portal#set-data-encryption-for-azure-database-for-postgresql-single-server) of Azure, there should be a **Data encryption** option under **Security**. But I don't see any option of Security.
[image]

Is there a way to enable that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the [Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/35531/private-endpoint-dont-support-postgresql-database.html):

> This feature is available in all Azure regions where Azure Database
> for PostgreSQL Single server supports General Purpose and Memory
> Optimized pricing tiers.

I was selecting **Basic** pricing tier, that's why there was no option appearing.

Answer (score 0):

While deploying the Azure PostgreSQL single server, in **Additional settings** you can see below statement:

> **The storage used for database and backup is encrypted by default with
> service managed keys.** Infrastructure Double Encryption is an
> additional infrastructure encryption layer using a secondary service
> managed key. Turning it ON can impact database performance.

Therefore, you don't need additional encryption for your data.

If you want double encryption for really sensitive data, you can enable **Infrastructure double encryption** option.

[image]

You can also refer my answer on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231011/where-to-specify-ssl-cert-file-and-alike-at-azure/70256076#70256076) if you need to implement SSL certificate in Azure PostgreSQL account.

Comment: I agree that the database is encrypted with service-managed keys by default. But what if I want to enable customer-managed keys (this option is available for many Azure services). And the documentation shows that I can enable for PostgreSQL db too.
I don't want to use double encryption as it can impact the performance of DB.

Comment: I think the document not updated yet. You can use customer SSL cert only. There isn't any other option.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was the storage. Data Encryption is possibile only for storage until 16TB and not for 4TB

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).